# Get the auto increment-primary key column programatically

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

witch is the auto increment field in a mysql table?

I have a table structure, for example: 
table name is my_table and the fields are my_id, my_name, my_blah.. The one of fields is an auto incremented primary key. Witch is it?

How can I get the name of auto increment field on this table with a php code and/or a mysql query?

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11093650/how-can-i-get-the-auto-incrementing-field-name-or-the-primary-key-fieldname-from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the MySQL [`SHOW COLUMNS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html) query to retrieve information about the columns in a table:

```
mysql> SHOW COLUMNS FROM `test`;
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| col1     | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| col2     | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The `extra` column will contain `auto_increment` for the primary key field.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with a

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM TableName
```

See here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html

Answer (score 0):

Use a MySQL client and issue the query [`SHOW CREATE TABLE my_table`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-create-table.html).

It shows you the code one needs to run to create that table. You can see the column names, types (and lengths), other attributes each column may have (they depend on the type). `AUTO_INCREMENT` is such an attribute.

It also shows you the `PK` and the indexes of the table.